# preventing session sharing in multiple browser

Tags: java, session, session-variables

I'm working on legacy java web application, when user log-in to application and click on Customer link (from customer list page), we're keeping customer info in session along with user info. Now if user want to work on multiple customer simultaneously (by opening the new customer in another browser), old customer in session will be replaced with new customer info. I understand that if we would've redesigned session (probably by keeping customer in hash map), this problem would have been solved. Is there any better approach to solve this issue ? I don't want user to login again when opening customer into new browser. I'm using IE8 as browser and application don't support multiple browser.

Comment: What happens if you spawn new session through the File->New Session menu?

Comment: If we spawn new session through the file -> new session, it will force user to login again, which we don't want.

Comment: further to my above comment, if i follow the step which is mentioned above and if i login again to app, it will have separate session as desired but as mentioned above, it forces again to login which is not desirable

Comment: A session work by the browser sending the server a token saying hey it's me. If you send a different token ie for a different session then the server needs to reauthenticate that it is you. So you need to keep using the session to prevent multiple logins. To allow multiple workflows in the same session each submit must tell the server what workflow it is using via a process level token instead of a session level token this is usually done by adding it to you pages as a hidden input which maps to the server side process.

Answer (score 0):

so you want one session with multiple states in it? 
Better depends purely on your architecture and use cases. 
But essentially you need to keep track of each customer instance and store that in each page/url. on each submit the customer id is interrogated and the appropriate customer is updated.